# FTP server monitoring

Tags: ftp, monitoring

I need to monitor some ftp servers for any changes in file structure, things that I need to monitor is how many times an file is downloaded (not sure if possible), if files are changed or not, if files are deleted or not, if ftp server still exists,

i would like this to be something that i can run server=side and would like a sms message or email if any of the above changes have occured

any one have any experience or would recommend an particular language or script?

thanks

Comment: just for reference, i don't want to install an ftp server, i just want something to help me monitor other ftp servers by periodically logging in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for php i use this simple script

<

```
?
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('show_errors', 1);
$file = "ftpfile.txt";
$handle = fopen($file, "r");

$date = new DateTime();
$date = $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$date = $date->format('U = Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

if(!filesize($file)>0) {
        echo "File is empty!";
    }
    else {
    while (($ftpservers = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

        //echo $ftpservers. "<br>";
        $ftpserver= explode ("<br>", $ftpservers );
        //$pattern = "//";
        //preg_match ($pattern, $ftpservers, $output);

        foreach ($ftpserver as $ftpserverurl) {
$ch = curl_init();                   //this part we set up curl 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$ftpserverurl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,40);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch))
{
sleep(2); //add sleep in order to not overload hosting server
$echooutput = $date. 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch). 'Server Malfunctioned:' .$ftpserverurl;
error_log("$echooutput", 3, "ftperrors.log"); //write error to log
error_log("$echooutput", 1, "your email address"); //email alert 
curl_close ($ch);


}
else
{
error_log("$date curl operation is sucessful \n", 3, "curl.log"); //keep track of successful connections for pattern anaylsis
curl_close ($ch);

}

        }

    }
    //if (!feof($handle)) {
        //echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    //}
    fclose($handle);






        }
?>
```